# Problem with Colliders and their rotation in the Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, scripting

The problem is that I what to create an openable door. This door should open when the player enter the Box Collider which is connected to the door. But the problem is when the door begins to open and to rotate, Collider starts to rotate too which brings me a lot of problems with usind such an idea. I try to create EmptyObject with its Collider but I can't connect this Collider with script and OnTriggerEnter function itself. Maybe I don't understand something, who knows, I'm just a begginer. How knows how to help, please write an answer.
My code if somebody needs it:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class openDoor : MonoBehaviour {

        public Vector3 Rotation_;
        private int i;
        public float speed;

        bool opentheDoor;
        bool closetheDoor;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            opentheDoor = false;
            closetheDoor = false;

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            if (opentheDoor == true) {
                this.transform.Rotate (Rotation_ * Time.deltaTime * speed);
                i += 1;
                    if (i == 70) {
                        opentheDoor = false;
                        i = 0;
                    }
            }

            if (closetheDoor == true) {
                this.transform.Rotate (-Rotation_ * Time.deltaTime * speed);
                i += 1;
                if (i == 70) {
                    closetheDoor = false;
                    i = 0;
                }
            }

        }

        void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {  
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") { {
               opentheDoor = true;
            }
            }
        }

        void OnTriggerExit (Collider other) {
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
                closetheDoor = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `i += 1;  if (i == 70) ...` do you really want to wait 70 **frames** ? What if the the framerate changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i would handle the scenerio

Take

### DoorHandler.cs

```
    public class DoorHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public Door door;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            door.OpenDoor();
        }
    }
}
```

This should be attached to Parent of the door.

Next Take

### Door.cs

```
public class Door : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isOpened = false;

    public void OpenDoor()
    {
        if (!isOpened)
        {
            isOpened = true;
            Debug.Log("OPEN");
            //OPEN DOOR CODE!
        }
    }
}
```

Attach this to the `Door` GameObject

### NOTE

The hierarchy would be like **DoorHandler->Door->DoorModel** (where Door is just an empty gameobject pivot of the Door)
[image]

In `DoorHandler` GameObject attach `BoxCollider` and Check Mark `IsTrigger`.

[image]

Also Player **SHOULD HAVE A RIGIDBODY** (preferably Kinametic) and obviously a collider

So When `Player` enters the DoorHandler's Collider -> The DoorHandler's `OnTriggerEnter`  will be triggered and finally Call the `Door` to `OpenDoor()`

Comment: One more question: Door-Handler is just an empty object with Box Collider?

Comment: Yes it is just an empty gameobject Object with Box Collider as trigger.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks a lot! You helped me a lot. I also needed the closing the door, but I have already done it. Thank you again! +rep)

Comment: Happy to Help! :D

Answer (score 1):

Add another check in OnTriggerEnter that checks if the door is currently opening or not.

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {  
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && !opentheDoor) {
           opentheDoor = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to immobilize the BoxCollider and that's answer is not what I wanted. But thank you in any way)

Comment: @ГлебБуткевич You can use a separate object (and trigger collider) from the door to detect the player. I didn't want you to freeze the box collider on the door because you don't want players clipping through the door when it is moving. Point being: what if you want a trigger area to be separate from the object that it affects? If you have a steel plate the player will walk over to open a door on the other side, do you really want those objects attached to the same hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

attach the door to an empty object. put the trigger on the empty object. then make the ontrigger entry rotate the door, not the paent object, and the collider will remain in place.

Parent
-child(door)
-child(collider)

Comment: So I have an EmptyObject called Door which rotates the door. There is the door itself called Body, and I tried to put some new EmptyObject with BoxCollider but Unity just ignore this Collider and door doesn't rotate. I did something's wrong, I guess...